# Trasfer data from S3 to Postgres RDS in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I am new to AWS and trying to find a way to load the data from `S3` to `RDS` . In my current approach I am using `EC2` instance to do that (where my app is running). I was thinking of doing through lambda but my data will have around (22 million records) and my current approach is taking 4hr. And lambda timeout is 15mins (So lambda approach does not work in this case).
The problem with my current approach is This data files comes may be like ones in a month and I don't want to have a EC2 running just of this task. Any alternatives in server-less world would be helpful.Thank You

Note: `The data is loaded from S3 to RDS based on SQS, i,e my application is pulling the messages from SQS which will then load the data into RDS`

Comment: 1. I'd consider using DMS. It can copy data from S3 to RDS
2. are you trying to analyze data? if so consider Athena or EMR

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan I am not going to analyze data, I can try using DMS. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please try DMS for this. You need to create DMS agent with S3 bucket info as source and target details of your RDS.